# How can I add padding between tick labels?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

How do add padding between chart labels. I need the tick labels to always show but how do I add spacing between the tick labels?

Another possible solution that would be fine is to make the chart just have a bigger height. This occurs only when shrinking the chart to size of the browser to less than 320px in width.

[image: image of overlapping labels]

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/leetcat/4d7juow3/

In my case the labels are "Healthy", "reacting","injured", "ill."

I have tried:

```
options: {
  layout: {
      padding: {
        top: 20
      }
    }
}
```

and

```
scales: { 
  yAxes: [{   
    ticks: {
      padding: 10
    }
  }]
}
```

Comment: if you go for the bigger height option, one way to do it is setting the height of the canvas after the chart renders, like this:  "ChartCanvas.attr('height',400);"

Comment: @LeonardoCabré One problem with setting of the whole canvas is then it is not as dynamic. This should also show on tablets. I also added it to the fiddle no change. https://jsfiddle.net/leetcat/4d7juow3/4/

Comment: sorry the code i wrote is jquery, witch is not included in the fiddle, to test it you have to include jquery library and change var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart"); for var ctx = $("#myChart");, then ctx.attr('height',400);

Comment: That makes the chart look weird. https://jsfiddle.net/leetcat/4d7juow3/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add `maintainAspectRatio: false` to the chart options, and set a min-height on the chart element.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");

var data = {
  labels: ["2017-09-26T00:00:00Z", "2017-09-27T00:00:00Z", "2017-09-28T00:00:00Z", "2017-09-29T00:00:00Z", "2017-09-30T00:00:00Z", "2017-10-01T00:00:00Z", "2017-10-02T00:00:00Z"],
  datasets: [{
    label: "Self Rating",
    backgroundColor: '#777777',
    borderColor: '#777777',
    data: [1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    fill: false,
    yAxisID: "y-axis-1",
  }]
};

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: data,
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    legend: {
      position: 'bottom',
    },
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Check-In History',
    },
    scales: {
      // Need to limit tick marks to be days
      xAxes: [{
        display: true,
        type: 'time',
        time: {
          unit: 'day',
          unitStepSize: 1,
          displayFormats: {
            'day': 'MMM DD'
          }
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        id: "y-axis-1",
        display: true,
        position: "left",
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Mental Health Continuum'
        },
        ticks: {
          min: 0,
          max: 3.05,
          stepSize: 1,
          suggestedMin: 0,
          suggestedMax: 3.05,
          callback: function(label, index, labels) {
            switch (label) {
              case 0:
                return 'Ill';
              case 1:
                return 'Injured';
              case 2:
                return 'Reacting';
              case 3:
                return 'Healthy';
            }
          }
        },
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#myChart {
  min-height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.0/Chart.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper">
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
```